# Is there a way to do conditional assignment to constants in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I would like to create an immutable value that is assigned different values depending on a condition. In Scala I would be able to write the following:

```
    let attribs = if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30, weight: UIFontWeightLight) ]
    } else {
        [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30) ]
    }
```

but since Swift if statements don't return the result of the executed code block that doesn't work.

If the test was for a normal Bool I could use the ternary conditional operator

```
    let attribs = #available(iOS 8.2, *) ?
        [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30, weight: UIFontWeightLight) ]
    :
        [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30) ]
```

but that doesn't work for the iOS version tests, I get the following error:

```
#available may only be used as condition of an 'if', 'guard' or 'while' statement.
```

I feel like I'm stuck with a var, but unless I also make it optional I end up with a double assignment in most cases, which seems so ugly and unnecessary?

```
    var attribs = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30) ]
    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
        [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30, weight: UIFontWeightLight) ]
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do the declaration and assignment on two separate lines:

```
let attribs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {
    attribs = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .light)]
} else {
    attribs = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
}
```

Even though it is a `let`, you can do the assignment (only once per path of execution) on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like this:

```
let value: String
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    value = "iOS 9 is available"
} else {
    value = "iOS 9 and up only"
}
print(value) // iOS 9 is available
```

Comment: This doesn't build, as you declared "value" as a let. This is a key piece of the OP.

Comment: It does build. Take a look at the second answer which is pretty much identical to this one. You should really test this before claiming something doesn't work.

Comment: Agreed. I was wrong. Learned my Swift lesson for the day!

Comment: Plus OP didn't mention which version of Swift he/she is using, therefore we assume the current version (3.0.1), using the current version of Xcode (8.1)

Comment: Oh yes it does build and it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The rule is: A "var" must be assigned a value at least once before it is used. A "let" must be assigned a value not more than once, and exactly once before it is used.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this

```
var someConstant: String {
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        return "iOS 9"
    } else {
        return "not iOS 9"
    }
}
```

By doing this you can't assign a value to the variable `someConstant` even if it is a `var` and not a `let` because it is a calculated property

Another way of doing this would be to use free functions.

```
let someConstant: String = {
    if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        return "iOS 9"
    } else {
        return "not iOS 9"
    }
}()
```

The difference between the first example from the second example is that the second example is only instantiated once.